# Improving ListView performace when laid on top of SurfaceView

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

I have a layout that looks similar to this:

[image]

As the sketch described, I used `SurfaceView` to receive and draw camera preview data. Said view is the overlaid by a `ListView` that contains several children  inside of it.

The main problem I'm faced with right now is the poor scrolling performance I got from `ListView`. I have absolutely no idea on why this happened, especially when the camera preview doesn't look stuttery at all.

That said, I've done some experiments by detaching the camera preview (yes, it's a `Fragment`) and the ListView's performance improved dramatically. So it's the camera preview that might've caused all this. But being such an important part of my Activity, removing it completely is not an option.

So, is there any way I could make my `ListView` scroll better? I'm also open for any alternative solution that you might have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wanted to say, I have a similar issue. But I experience a different behaviour on different devices. Galaxy Note (SM-P600), which is the more powerful device performs very badly. The Galaxy Tab, which is older performs quite good. There are huge resolution differences involved though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution for this issue. Usually the surfaceView is processed by the gpu. Atleast it is hardware accelerated. On newer devices the ListView is hardware accelerated too. If the processing of the surfaceView is heavy, it consumes alot of processing power. By turning of the hardware acceleration with `listView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` you can get your listview processed by the cpu. This way you don't get the best performance possible for a listview, but you get a decent result, which does not depend on the surfaceView load.